# Settings are not being saved in my app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Firstly, I am a beginner in Java.

**Problem**  :

None of the settings are being saved in my app. I am trying to work on an app that was made before. When I change language or settings in my app it gets reverted to new after I restart the app.

Here is the code.

```
    package com.studioninja.CleanerAppLock;


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        String preferenceKey = preference != null ? preference.getKey() : "";

        if (preferenceKey.equals(getString(R.string.pref_key_language))) {
            return handleLanguagePreferenceClick();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_language))
                .setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);        
    }

    private boolean handleLanguagePreferenceClick() {
        LanguagesDialog languagesDialog = new LanguagesDialog();
        languagesDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "LanguagesDialogFragment");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why would you want to have your app have a different language than OSs default? 
Android has excellent multi language support, but it will alway prefer system setting, which makes sense.

Comment: The app is targeted to Nepali Users. There are lots of Nepali user's who understand Nepal well while there is problem for them to understand Nepali.

Comment: Well nepali is supported by android https://www.screencast.com/t/tRtCb9qq8F0
So you can just copy string.xml to a new folder in res/values-ne and add translation there. So when Device is set to nepali your application will be in that language

Comment: Sorry But I have already done this. Its working well but the problem is its not being saved while refreshing app.

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshing" app?

Comment: I mean when I close and open app

Comment: If you defined your strings right and set OS language setting so Nepali, and you're still getting different language than you must be overriding language on application start.
You should probably give more information on what are you trying to achieve here...

Comment: I have app that was running ok in english. Now I added Nepali Language , it works but when I restart apps it starts in English language. Language setting is not saved.